# Using external style sheet in Birt

Tags: css, birt

I'm creating a simple external style sheet that I want to apply to my birt reports and am having problems from the style sheet elements not being loaded in the report or even when the are loaded if I try to render as a PDF or an HTML page the styles I defined are no longer applied. Below is my example style sheet.

```
.report-label
{
    color: #365F91;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: left;
}

.report-data
{
    color: #000000;
}
```

I try to apply this as a style by going to the rptdesign outline. Right clicking "Styles" and selecting "Use CSS File..." Once the Style sheet is loaded I go to the report element I want the style applied to and in the General Tab there is a style section with a dropdown menu where I can select the style to apply. For example I might select ".report-label" and in the Layout of the report it looks like the style is applied. However when I run it as PDF or HTML the style is no longer applied.

Also at times as I'm making changes to the CSS sheet I reload what I've done and all the items in the CSS file disappear and I can no longer access them to even apply a style.
If I take the exact code though and copy it to a new file then use that css file instead then I can access them again. Any advice on how to get this working properly so that everything is still there when I generate a PDF and HTML report would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In addition to loading CSS files with the "Use CSS" dialog of BIRT Designer, you can load external stylesheets into your BIRT report using the head.js script in the clientScripts > clientInitialize portion of your report layout.

For example,

```
head.js("http://localhost/sample.css",function() {
    // Call a function when done
    console.log("Done loading external CSS");
});
```

Then include your HTML in text items in the report.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and it is working for me. With a BIRT designer 4.4:

- i created a file test.css in the same Eclipse project than BIRT reports
- Copied your styling rules report-label & report-data into this file
- Included test.css in the report with "Use css files", leaving option "Include css at  runtime" unchecked.
- Applied report-label & report-data to report elements as you mentionned

When running the report these styles are correctly applied both in html and pdf formats. After changing the color of report-label class to "green" in test.css, this change is immediately taken into consideration when the report is being executed.

May be you should provide a sample report showing the problem and specifiy where you have put your css file, it would be easier to find out what is wrong in your case.

Comment: Hmm I'm not using the newest version of Birt. I will try updating mine to see if it works. Thank you for trying it.

Comment: For the most part everything is working except for the font-weight is not working